# Parsing error: Identifier 'Router' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

Please how do I resolve this error?

> ./src/components/Router.js
> Line 8:7:  Parsing error: Identifier 'Router' has already been declared

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import StorePicker from './StorePicker';
import App from "./App";
import NotFound from "./NotFound";
 

class Router extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={StorePicker} />
                    <Route path="/store/:storeid" component={App} />
                    <Route  component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default Router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined a class named `Router` but you already imported `Router` from `'react-router-dom'` (which is not used anywhere)

so, just replace

`import { BrowserRouter, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';`

by

`import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';`